# making http server with node and browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

im making a mobile app that require a http server so im trying to make it with browserify so this is what im doing, i got this server.js

```
    var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

then i do this

$ browserify server.js > browserify.js

then i enmbeded to my html like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

then when i run the html i get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: http.createServer is not a function
```

how can i get a http server working on the browser ?

by the way i got http-browserify installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies if I'm reading this question wrong, but you can't create an http server from within a browser. That `http.createServer` call is only meant to be called (and is only defined) in node.js.

So you would need to run your script from node from the command line, like this:

```
node https.js
```

Comment: Thats why im using broserify, so i can run node codes in the browser

Comment: Browserify does not let you run node.js code in the browser. Its purpose is to let you use node.js-style "require" directives to organize your javascript dependencies.

Comment: Ok i got it now, thanks for your help, im closing the question

Comment: The `http` module used by http-browserify doesn't have a `createServer` method: https://github.com/substack/http-browserify. Even if it did, how would it would it even work? Will others be able to connect to your browser?

Comment: I believe the author's approach is somehow similar to what I'd like to achieve, which is:

1. You have a node based service deployed on some server
2. Use want to deploy the same functionality to a single user
3. You simply use the same code, but run it in the browser (eg in a service worker) and change the URL in your client

May seem crazy, but it's simply a code reuse (assuming your node code can run in the browser, eg all it does is making requests to other endpoints).

Comment: @TobiaszCudnik Great idea to use a service worker as the in-browser "server". I'm not entirely convinced that this is what the author was going for, but a clever way to reuse code nonetheless.